# Showing a circular cylinder is a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading the book "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Andrew Pressley.

I am trying to show the circular cylinder $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} \mid x^2 + y^2 =1\}$  can be covered by a single surface patch and so is a surface.

The hint is to let $U$ be an annulus.

We have an open set $U=\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid 0<u^2 + v^2 < \pi\}$.

We also let $r=(u^2+v^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ Why?

We then let $\delta :U\to \mathbb{R^3}$ defined by $\delta(u,v)=(\frac{u}{r} \cdot \frac{v}{r} \cdot \tan(r-\frac{\pi}{2}))$

How can we see that the circular cylinder $S$ can be covered by a single surface patch?

What does it mean to say "covered by a surface patch"?

What is the difference between a surface and a surface patch?

Comment: I think you need two surface patches, don't you?

Comment: "S is covered by a single surface patch" means, that $S$ is homeomorphic to an open subset $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. A homeomorphism of $U$ and $S$ is called a surface patch.

Comment: The unit cylinder $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ or any annulus. In your case, where $U=\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid 0<u^2 + v^2 < \pi\}$, you can take  $\sigma : U \to S, \, (u,v) \to (\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}, \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}, \ln(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}} - 1))$ or $\sigma : U \to S, \, (u,v) \to (\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}, \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}, \tan(\sqrt{u^2 + v^2} - \frac{pi}{2}))$. To see that these patches cover the whole $S$, take any point $p \in S$ and find $(u,v) \in U$ s.t. $\sigma(u,v) = p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can cover it by the two surface patchs : $$\sigma_1 : (0,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^3}$$ $$\sigma_1(\theta,z)=(cos\theta,sin\theta,z)$$ and $$\sigma_2 : (-\pi,\pi)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^3}$$ $$\sigma_2(\theta,z)=(cos\theta,sin\theta,z)$$
"covered by surface patch" means (for example) that the support of $\sigma$ ; $\sigma((0,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R})$ is exactly the surface S, if it's not the case you must cover it by at least two surface paths.

Comment: I am new to this and struggling to wrap my head around this concept.  Why is the function you have mentioned special?And how can you rigorously  check if a surface patch covers the whole surface?

Comment: You must show that every point of S is in the image of at least one of the surface patches $\sigma_1$ or $\sigma_2$.˜

Comment: Thank you, lastly what is the difference between surface and a surface patch?

Comment: A surface patch is a parametrization of a part of a surface, this part can be the entire surface.

Comment: @Mathstudent this is not the answer. Moreover, it can be easily covered by a single surface patch.